# Laptop shuts down when I'm playing graphically demanding game and it's not pugged in. [Ubuntu 20.04]

Tags: 20.04, power-management, shutdown, battery, overheating

When I play some small games or simply watching YouTube and my laptop isn't plugged in, it will work fine till 0% battery. But when I run some high graphically demanding game and unplug charger, the laptop will shut down immediately, even if it's fully charged.
Is it some power management issue, or is it overheat?
How can I fix it?

Laptop: Dell G3 15 3579, GTX 1050 Ti, i5-8300H.

Games: divinity original sin 2, Dark Souls 3, Tekken 7.

Comment: Add more details like name and model of laptop, name of the _graphically demanding game_, etc.